# Break in if statement

Tags: java

I have a switch method, and I want that if the type of fetch is ALL, the switch runs in all the statments, (HOUSE AND PLAYER), but it doesn't work because of the break, it only runs in HOUSE, removing the break works, but then if the type is not ALL, it will also runs on the others statments and not only in the given type. Whats is a proper solution for that?

```
public static void fetch(FetchType fetchType) {
    switch (updateType) {
        case ALL: // if this is the case, then it should run for HOUSE, PLAYER
        case HOUSE:
             // code here
             break;
        case PLAYER:
             // code here
             break;
        default: 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `case ALL: /* code in HOUSE-case*/; /* code in PLAYER-case*/; break;` If the code in the `HOUSE`- and/or `PLAYER`-case is lengthy, extract it in method(s) and also call this (those) method(s) in the `ALL`-case.

Comment: @Turing85, you may have an example code, there is something that I do not understand, i'm somewhat confused about the last thing you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can either create private methods for that:

```
public static void fetch(FetchType fetchType) {
    switch (updateType) {
        case ALL: 
             doHouse();
             doPlayer();
             break;
        case HOUSE:
             doHouse();
             break;
        case PLAYER:
             doPlayer();
             break;
        default: 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
private static void doHouse(){ ... }
private static void doPlayer(){ ... }
```

Or use `Runnable` to avoid using polluting the local private namespace:

```
public static void fetch(FetchType fetchType) {
    Runnable house = () -> { ... };
    Runnable player = () -> { ... };
    switch (updateType) {
        case ALL: 
             house.run();
             player.run();
             break;
        case HOUSE:
             house.run();
             break;
        case PLAYER:
             player.run();
             break;
        default: 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you might need to create methods for each case in the Main class and then call all methods if the fetch type is "ALL"

```
static void methodForHouse() {
    System.out.println("I just got executed!");
  }
static void methodForPlayer() {
    System.out.println("I just got executed!");
  }
```

And then

```
public static void fetch(FetchType fetchType) {
    switch (updateType) {
        case ALL:
        methodForHouse();
        methodForPlayer();
        break;
        case HOUSE:
             methodForHouse();
             break;
        case PLAYER:
             methodForPlayer();
             break;
        default: 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```